# Gstreamer smb link for playbin2 uri

Tags: android, gstreamer, smb, playbin2

I am trying to play a video file located in windows pc using gstreamer playbin2 on android.
My uri is as follows

"smb://xxxxx-pc/share/1.mp4"

The error says : Error code from element uridecodebin0: No URI handler implemented for smb.

Is it that smb URI support is not provided for android , if it is , is there a work around.

Thanks in advance.